# Utilizando um FB.Api dentro de outro FB.Api

Tags: javascript, facebook

Estou fazendo uma função para fazer uma lista com 10 amigos do facebook com 10 posts (status) cada. O código abaixo realiza as buscas de forma certeira, no entanto a div "friend" + id não recebe o conteúdo na linha divFriendsPost.innerHTML = friendPosts, ainda que o conteúdo esteja correto.

JS

```
FB.api('/me/friends?limit=10', function(fResponse) {
    console.dir(fResponse);
    var divFriendsList = document.getElementById('friendsList');
    var friend_data = fResponse.data.sort(sortMethod);
    var newLine = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < friend_data.length; i++) {
        newLine += '<p>';
        newLine += '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + friend_data[i].id + '/picture">';
        newLine += '<em>' + friend_data[i].name + '</em>';
        newLine += '</p>';
        newLine += '<div id="friend' + friend_data[i].id + '" class="friendPosts"></div>';

        FB.api({method: 'fql.query', query: 'SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = ' + friend_data[i].id + ' LIMIT 10'},
            function(posts){
                var divFriendsPost = document.getElementById('friend' + friend_data[i].id);
                var friendPosts = '';
                for(var j=0; j < posts.length ; j++) {
                    friendPosts += '<p>' + posts[j].message + '</p>';
                }
                divFriendsPost.innerHTML = friendPosts;
            }
    );
    }
    divFriendsList.innerHTML = newLine;
});
```

Pelo o que li, tem a ver com a requisição assíncrona. Como se resolve isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que as divs ainda não estão no dom quando você faz o "document.getElementById('friend'..." e com isso a var divFriendsPost fica vazia. Portanto, se você inserir a newline dentro do for deve dar certo. Algo como:

```
FB.api('/me/friends?limit=10', function(fResponse) {
    console.dir(fResponse);
    var divFriendsList = document.getElementById('friendsList');
    var friend_data = fResponse.data.sort(sortMethod);
    for(var i = 0; i < friend_data.length; i++) {
        var newNode = document.createElement('div');
        var newLine = '<p>';
        newLine += '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + friend_data[i].id + '/picture">';
        newLine += '<em>' + friend_data[i].name + '</em>';
        newLine += '</p>';
        newLine += '<div id="friend' + friend_data[i].id + '" class="friendPosts"></div>';
        newNode.innerHTML = newLine;
        divFriendList.appendChild(newNode);
        FB.api({method: 'fql.query', query: 'SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = ' + friend_data[i].id + ' LIMIT 10'},
            function(posts){
                var divFriendsPost = document.getElementById('friend' + friend_data[i].id);
                var friendPosts = '';
                for(var j=0; j < posts.length ; j++) {
                    friendPosts += '<p>' + posts[j].message + '</p>';
                }
                divFriendsPost.innerHTML = friendPosts;
            }
        );
    }
});
```